# Changing the origin of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Let $F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$ be a power series with disk of convergence $D(z_0,R)$. Let $z_1\in D(z_0,R)$. Show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n (z-z_1)^n$ where $b_n:= \sum_{m=n}^\infty \dbinom{m}{n} a_m (z_1-z_0)^{m-n}$, converges to $F(z)$ on the disk $D(z_1, R-|z_1-z_0|)$.

I begin with
$$ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a_m((z-z_1)-(z_1-z_0))^m = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{m} \dbinom{m}{n} a_m(z_1-z_0)^{m-n}(z-z_1)^n$$
then I apply the following [sum interchange formula](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m321/twosum.pdf), defining 
$$c_{mn} := \dbinom{m}{n}a_m(z_1-z_0)^{m-n} \text{ if } m \ge n, \text{ and } c_{mn}:= 0 , \text{ if } m<n$$
This yields the result as $\sum_m \sum_n |c_{mn}| < \infty$ holds from convergence of $F(z)$.

---

I wonder if there is a neater way that rigorously proves the statement.